# Azure devops multiple python version with python 3

Tags: python, azure-devops

I'd like to setup an Azure Pipeline for Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7.
However there are some scripts that will always need access to python 3.
I.e. the launcher scripts will always use Python 3, and that launcher script will in turn launch subprocesses in Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Is it possible in your PC? if yes, it's possible also in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thanks for that response, i've now updated the question to be more specific about asking for a solution

Comment: The same question - how do you do in your PC?

Comment: I know this is old, but here is the answer -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version?view=azure-devops#how-can-i-configure-a-self-hosted-agent-to-use-this-task